# PostgreSQL 9.2 tstzrange null/infinity CONSTRAINT CHECK

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, postgresql-9.2, data-integrity

I'd like to limit a PostgreSQL 9.2 tstzrange to valid dates at both ends. No NULLs nor 'infinity'.

Various revisions of this SQL isn't constraining '-/+infinity' input:

```
CREATE TABLE bill
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  period tstzrange NOT NULL,
  -- other columns
  CONSTRAINT bill_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_lower_not_null_ck CHECK (lower(period) IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_upper_not_null_ck CHECK (upper(period) IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_lower_not_infinity_ck CHECK (lower_inf(period) IS FALSE),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_upper_not_infinity_ck CHECK (upper_inf(period) IS FALSE)
);


INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange (NULL, NULL));
INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange ('2000-05-10', '2015-02-22');
INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange ('2000-05-10', now());
INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange ('infinity', now());
INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange ('-infinity', now());
INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange (now(), 'infinity');


psql (9.2.3)
Type "help" for help.

test_1=> SELECT id, period FROM bill;
 id |                           period
----+------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | ["2000-05-10 00:00:00+01","2015-02-22 00:00:00+00")
  2 | ["2000-05-10 00:00:00+01","2013-10-16 13:20:01.793803+01")
  4 | [-infinity,"2013-10-16 13:20:18.993038+01")
  5 | ["2013-10-16 13:21:14.208279+01",infinity)
(4 rows)
```

Changing the `*_inf(period) IS FALSE` checks to `TRUE` rejects valid dates.

[Range functions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html)

Thoughts?

Comment: I think this works: `CHECK (NOT(period @> '-infinity'::timestamp with time zone))` and similar for `+infinity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple checks work as desired:

```
CHECK ( lower(period) > '-infinity' )
```

and

```
CHECK ( upper(period) < 'infinity' )
```

Therefore, you can have:

```
CREATE TABLE bill
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  period tstzrange NOT NULL,
  -- other columns
  CONSTRAINT bill_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_lower_not_null_ck CHECK (lower(period) IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_upper_not_null_ck CHECK (upper(period) IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_lower_not_infinity_ck 
    CHECK ( lower(period) > '-infinity' ),
  CONSTRAINT bill_period_upper_not_infinity_ck 
    CHECK ( upper(period) < 'infinity' )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `NULL` is not excluded.

i.e: This works: `INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange (NULL, NULL));`

as does this: 
`INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange (NULL, now()));`

and this too:
`INSERT INTO bill (period) VALUES (tstzrange (now(), NULL));`

Comment: Oops, you are right. Not sure what I was checking - or thinking.

Comment: Yes, after testing - those 4 now work together. Thanks.

Comment: You could combine them, with `CHECK (lower(period) IS NOT NULL AND lower(period) > '-infinity')` if you like. Or even all 4 in one CHECK constraint.

Comment: Great minds think alike as I've just tested this single: `CONSTRAINT bill_period_not_null_nor_infinity_ck CHECK  
  (  
 lower(period) IS NOT NULL AND  
 upper(period) IS NOT NULL AND  
 (lower(period) > '-infinity') AND  
 (upper(period) < 'infinity')  
  )`